# Double Quotes cannot be inserted in database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

I am using codeigniter and mysql for web development. I have also used a rich-text editor called tinymce editor. My problem is I have applied the text-editor in a textarea. When I applied  header and paragraph tags and etc its all okay but when I used to "center" the text it used  the "style" tag of css, like style="text-align:center;" but when I insert it to database it does not include the double quotes "" the thing it will insert is only the style= and it will not include the "" and inside it.

```
The code below is used to insert data from the form including the textarea that was applied with the tinymce text-editor.

$("#send_email").click(function()
   {


    $("#myModal_loader").modal('show');
    var email_add = $("#email").val();
    var email_subject = $("#email_subject").val();
    var email_message = tinymce.get('email_message').getContent();


    var postData   = {
                      'email_add':email_add,
                      'email_subject':email_subject,
                      'email_message':email_message
                    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>students/send_email",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: postData,
        success: function(data)
        {
        $("#myModal_loader").modal('hide');
        $("#myModal_confirm").modal('show');

        $("#email_subject").val("");
        $("#email_message").val("");

        console.log();


        }



    });
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);

   return false;

    });
    });
    </script>
```

controller

```
      $this->course_booking_model->insert_email_data
      ($stored_email,$tennant_email,$email_subject,$email_message);
```

model

```
    function insert_email_data($email_add,$tennant_email,$email_subject,$email_message)         {

  for($i=0;$i<count($email_add);$i++){

  $data = array(
     'email_add'     => $email_add[$i],
     'tennant_email' => $tennant_email,
     'email_subject' => $email_subject,
     'email_message' => $email_message
     );


        $this->db->set('time_sent','NOW()',FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('email', $data);
              }

               }
```

Comment: which field is the issue ? `email_message`?

Comment: the email message is the issue here because it has html tags and css inline styling which contains double quotes like style="text-align:center". the quotes after the equal sign is not read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI documentation : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

```
$this->db->insert();
Note: All values are escaped automatically producing safer queries.
```

you need to use

```
$this->db->set('field', $field_value,FALSE); //FALSE will disable the automatic escaping.
```

Comment: this is only applicable if you insert a single column. In my case I need to insert a an array of data.

Comment: you can use `db->query()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in here is that the formatted value from the textarea being passed from view to controller using ajax is that it does not read all the html tags because it escapes the double quotation in the codes, does passing incomplete html tags.

What I did was before the formatted value will be passed I removed the double quotes and replaced it using the code below.

```
var new_message = email_message.replace(/"/g, '\'');
```

and it solved the problem.